# Angular : how to deal with Asynchronous issues?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ngoninit

I m struggling to deal with what I thing is asynchronous issue with Angular 6.
here is an example. I just want to get into the 'if' and display the console log, but it never happens. getListOne and getListTwo call an Observable  API and are well displayed on my html.

```
ListOne = [];
ListTwo = [];

    ngOninit() {

    this.getListOne();
    this.getListTwo();

    if (this.ListTwo.length > 0 ) {
        console.log("well done at least !";
    }

    }
```

Comment: You can create variables like `listOneLoaded = false` and `listTwoLoaded = false` initially and in the `this.getListOne();  this.getListTwo();` methods you can set them `true` and in your if condition check for those variables to become `true`

Answer (score 1):

use forkJoin

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/forkJoin';  


forkJoin( this.getListOne(), this.getListTwo()).subscribe((result: any[]) => {
       console.log("well done at least !";
}
```

forkJoin require all input observables to be completed, but it also returns an observable that produces a single value that is an array of the last values produced by the input observables. In other words, it waits until the last input observable completes, and then produces a single value and completes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `subscribe` to observables like:

```
this.getListTwo().subscribe((result) => {
   if(result.length > 0){
    console.log("well done at least !");
   }
});
```

But since these are two observables and they complete in different times, you need to combine them and subscribe to the combined observable:

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

combineLatest(
    this.getListOne(),
    this.getListTwo()
).pipe(
   tap(([listOneResult, listTwoResult]) => {
     if(listTwoResult.length > 0){
       console.log("well done at least !");
     }
   })
)
```

But I think you need to know more about the observable fundamentals. Here is the docs about Observables:
https://angular.io/guide/observables